multiple If statements in power query and also summing the total
I have this written in DAX but I actually have to write it in Power Query.  I need a column that adds a 1 if the other columns do not equal "NA" and then adds the 1s together.  So if column 1, 2, and 3 were yes and column 4 and 5 were NA then the new column would be the number three.
1. new column = 
IF(table[column_1)]<>"NA",1,0)+
IF(table[column_2]<>"NA",1,0)+
IF(table[column_3)]<>"NA",1,0)+
IF(table[column_4)]<>"NA",1,0)+
IF(table[column_5)]<>"NA",1,0)

I have tried this but am getting an error:
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Addition", each List.Sum({each if [#"column 1"]<>"NA" then 1 else 0}, {each if [#"column 2"]<>"NA" then 1 else 0}, type number))


If adding a column using GUI:
= List.Count(List.FirstN(List.Transform(
  {[column_1], [column_2], [column_3], [column_4], [column_5]},
  each if _ <> "NA" then 1 else null),
  each _ <> null))

Or if editing the code directly:
#"Added Custom" =
Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStepName",
    "Custom",
    each List.Count(List.FirstN(List.Transform(
        {[column_1], [column_2], [column_3], [column_4], [column_5]},
        each if _ <> "NA" then 1 else null),
    each _ <> null)))


If you don't want to have to code each column name, or if the number of columns might vary, you can create a list of the relevant column values by using the Record.FieldValues function within the Table.AddColumn function.
In the below code, I assumed the only other columns in the table were those that needed to be included in the count. If that is not the case, there are various List functions that can return only the relevant column values, depending on how they are defined and ordered.
Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step","your_new_column_name", (r)=> 
         List.Count(List.Select(Record.FieldValues(r), each _ <> "NA")), Int64.Type)


It doesn't answer the original question. Your formula counts the number of non-NAs, but doesn't return the position of the last non-NA, as per the question "So if column 1, 2, and 3 were yes and column 4 and 5 were NA then the new column would be the number three."

@Michal I interpreted his question differently from you. Examine his DAX.
